# Task/Services has high CPU, but how to find out what it is doing?

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, cpu-usage

nearly daily some service is starting a task and never finishs. This task uses an entiry cpu core, which results in high fan activity.

Using ProcessExplorer I found out that it might be a service which is running and never stopping. But I simple can't figure out which service.

From ProcessExplorer it's said:

```
Command Line: taskhost.exe Time
```

And

```
Parent: services.exe(808)
```

Some help on figuring this out would really be appreciated.

(I already googled a lot, stopped services, looked through all services)

Some information:

- I'm not sure, but I think the problem is there since I bought the notebook (Dell XPS 12 Duo). Thought it was some Dell or Intel software and removed a lot of the preinstalled things
- Always had a antivirus software running (Antivir Premiun and now Kaspersky Pure)

*After* asking the question I've updated the following drivers/software, maybe one of them was the cause:

- Dell BIOS A04 -> A05
- Intel Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework
- Intel Smart Connect

**Update**

Still have the issue 3 years.

What else I tried:

- Complete reinstallation, even used Windows 8 again -> still the same
- Using [Snappy Driver Installer](https://sdi-tool.org) to really get latest drivers
- Used Linux for a while -> This **works**, so it is just some problem with Windows

Comment: use xperf t see the cause: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140264

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks for the tip, will try this, the next time the problem occurs.

Comment: I also have a Dell XPS12 with similar issues. Seems to be worst when I open the lid (even though it has not gone into sleep mode). I have SSD and 8Gb RAM, so it should be runnning like lightning. To fix, I need to kill Outlook and then restart it, as that seems the app most affected. But I do not yet think it is the answer. It can take 20 minutes to catch up. I will check my patch and BIOS levels and come back.

Answer (score 1):

`services.exe (808)` if it is running under `C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k DcomLaunch` then its a possible sign of trojan or the rootkit which is connected to an external host and trying to suck up the resourses. I would suggest scanning the PC using Hitman Pro or any other good anti-virus in safe mode with networking. You can access safe mode with networking while tapping <kbd>F8</kbd> key during windows startup run the scan only in administrator mode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but doesn't seem to be the answer for me. Did a scan with Hitman Pro and a full scan with Kaspersky. Also the problem seems to be there since I bought the notebook (I will update my question).

Answer (score 0):

**Enter system BIOS and reset to default options.**

Side note:
I'm still using my old XPS, as it is still a very good device. And there still was this issue. Finally I stumbled upon a forum thread where someone suggested to switch some specific setting within the BIOS.
My Dell doesn't allow to (nearly) set anything within the BIOS, so I decided to just reset the BIOS to default settings. And voila, this seemed to resolve the issue.